# Rails: undefined local variable or method 'user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm currently on chapter 9 of Hartl's tutorial.  I just added a few tests to check that the 'edit' page works.  The tests should be passing according to the tutorial but 5 of them failed.  I think the mistake might be in my user_pages_spec.rb file (posted below).  According to the command line, there is something wrong with it: 'undefined local variable or method 'user' '.

```
C:\Sites\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/
............................................FFFFF

Failures:

  1) User pages signup with valid information
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
::Nested_4::Nested_3::Nested_3:0x5259a68>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (requi
red)>'

  2) User pages signup with valid information
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
::Nested_4::Nested_3::Nested_3:0x52b0810>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (requi
red)>'

  3) User pages signup with valid information
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
::Nested_4::Nested_3::Nested_3:0x5339058>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (requi
red)>'

  4) User pages signup with valid information
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
::Nested_4::Nested_3::Nested_3:0x53abec8>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (requi
red)>'

  5) User pages signup with valid information
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
::Nested_4::Nested_3::Nested_3:0x5412630>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (requi
red)>'

Finished in 1.03 seconds
49 examples, 5 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:52 # User pages signup with valid infor
mation
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:53 # User pages signup with valid infor
mation
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:55 # User pages signup with valid infor
mation
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:54 # User pages signup with valid infor
mation
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:56 # User pages signup with valid infor
mation
```

user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end
  end
    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_title(new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { expect(user.reload.name).to  eq new_name }
      specify { expect(user.reload.email).to eq new_email }
    end
  end
end
```

users.controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end     

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Comment: you have `end` which closes describe block where `user` is defined. Format your code with valid indentions and recheck your blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `describe "edit" do` block. You initiate the user variable there, but then you end the block before starting the `describe "with valid information" do` block. So the user variable doesn't get passed on.

I would create the user in a `before` block at the very top of the spec, like so:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  before { user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  subject { page }

  ...

end
```

When you do that, the user variable will be available to all the specs you define. This is also cleaner, since you won't have to recreate it over and over.

Comment: Thanks! I just removed the second 'end' in the edit do block and put it towards the bottom of the file, is that a bad method?

Comment: That's fine too. What I suggested just eliminates the need to keep recreating the user object inside each spec. But for your tutorial (which I also went through once), it doesn't really matter. :)